# Material UI Autocomplete default value with multiple selection

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui

I have a `Material UI Autocomplete` component that have `multiple selection` and I need some default values.

My problem is with `checkbox selection`. The names are there in text field, but they are not selected as values.

This is my component:

```
<Autocomplete
    multiple
    className={classes.select}
    disableCloseOnSelect
    options={users}
    value={consistenceUser}
    onChange={handleUserChange}
    defaultChecked={consistenceUser}
    getOptionLabel={(option) => (option.name)}
    renderOption={(option, { selected }) => (
        <React.Fragment>
            <Checkbox
                icon={icon}
                checkedIcon={checkedIcon}
                style={{ marginRight: 8 }}
                checked={selected}
            />
            {option.name}
        </React.Fragment>
    )}
    renderTags={option => renderUserValues(userValue)}
    renderInput={(params) => (
        <TextField
            {...params}
            label={i18n.t("worklogModal.user")}
            variant="outlined"
        />
    )}
/>
<Typography className={classes.errorText}>
    {userError}
</Typography>
```

Where `consistenceUser` is an `array of user objects` and `userValue` is an `array of user ids`.

This is the method that renders the user names in textfield, which works great, but they are not selected when I add them as default value.

```
const renderUserValues = selected => {
        if (selected) {
            let shownValues = users.filter(user => selected.includes(user.id)).map(user => { return user.name })
            return [...shownValues].join(", ")
        }
    }
```

Is there something wrong that i've done?

Thnak you for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### SOLUTION

Might sound easy and rookie, but I found the solution and is pretty simple.

I added `getOptionSelected={(option, value) => option.id === value.id}` and now my `default values` are selected and it works as it should.

Hope will help someone one day!